# Creating a Git project from scratch

Tags: gitlab, git

I'm new to Git, and I have trouble creating a repo. I have written a Python script in an already-existent folder that contains lots of files. I want to create a project that contains this script and a `readme.md` file. I did this in the command line:

```
$ mkdir Project
$ cd Project
```

and I get:

```
Initialized empty Git repository in C:/Users/me/Project/.git/
```

Then I used `git add myFile.py`and it says that it doesn't match any files.

Do I need to move `myFile.py` to a certain folder? Can I simply create this project in GitLab?

I am sorry for the possibly trivial questions, but I have never worked with this before.

Comment: `I did this in the command line: [...] and I get:` I _really_ doubt that this is what happened. If you have a project in an existing directory you should init your git repository _in that directory_, not create a new one.

Comment: Agreed.  Your question is confusing to me, because I don't know what steps you actually took.  Type `ls` and check if you see `myFile.py` anywhere.  Then, type `git status` and have a look at what is going on.  If you see a message saying that you're in a Git repository, then you in the wrong location.

Comment: Neither `mkdir` nor `cd` will result in that output. Looks more like the output from `git init`: what exactly did you do (please *update the question*).

Answer (score 2):

I try to answer at your main question: **Creating a Git project from scratch**

First of all you have to create a remote repository on your prefer hosting provider: GitHub, GitLab or BitBucket... *Create your new repository*

Follow these steps (the example was based on new GitHub repository):

1 - Create your project on your local machine

```
$ mkdir Project
$ cd Project
```

2 -Init git project inside your Project folder

```
$ git init
```

3 - Work with your project or whatelse

```
$ touch README.md
$ mkdir yourfolder
$ touch yourfolder/file.py
```

4 - Git flow to publish your project into hosting provider

```
$ git add README.md
$ git add yourfolder/file.py
$ git commit -m "your message"
$ git remote add origin https://github.com/-YOURUSERNAME-/Project.git
$ git push -u origin master
```

This is a pdf cheatsheet of git commands: https://services.github.com/on-demand/downloads/github-git-cheat-sheet.pdf